# Unexpected input \ does not allow character identification in string

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below

```
string<-"[\"TV\", \"Hair dryer\",\"Dryer\", \"Heating\", \"Kitchen\", \"Wifi\", \"Air conditioning\", \"Hangers\", \"Washer\", \"Iron\", \"Elevator\", \"Essentials\"]"                                                                                          
string2<-"[\"TV\", \"Hair dryer\", \"Heating\", \"Kitchen\", \"Wifi\", \"Air conditioning\", \"Hangers\", \"Washer\", \"Iron\", \"Elevator\", \"Essentials\"]"                                                                                          
value<-c(string,string2)
name<-c("hOUSE","HOUSE2")
D<-data.frame(value,name)
```

and I want to create a new variable which will contain the number `1` if both `Washer` and `Dryer` are included in the string otherwise it will contain `0`. Im trying with:

```
D$WasherDryer <- ifelse(str_detect(D$value, \"Washer\" && \"Dryer\"), 1, 0)
```

but it cant work. How can I replace this `\`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to pass the words as a vector in `map`, and `reduce` with `&`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
D <- D %>%
     mutate(WasherDryer = map_int(c("Washer", "Dryer"), 
         ~ str_detect(value, .x) %>% 
              reduce(`&`) %>% 
                as.integer))
```

-output

```
 D                                                                                                                               #value
#1 ["TV", "Hair dryer","Dryer", "Heating", "Kitchen", "Wifi", "Air conditioning", "Hangers", "Washer", "Iron", "Elevator", "Essentials"]
#2         ["TV", "Hair dryer", "Heating", "Kitchen", "Wifi", "Air conditioning", "Hangers", "Washer", "Iron", "Elevator", "Essentials"]
#    name WasherDryer
#1  hOUSE           1
#2 HOUSE2           0
```

---

Or if we want to use a regex, make sure to have two alternatives - 1) 'Washer' word can precede 'Dryer' or it can succeed so that both cases can be checked

```
D$WasherDryer <- as.integer(str_detect(D$value, "\\bWasher\\b.*\\bDryer\\b|\\bDryer\\b.*\\bWasher\\b"))
D$WasherDryer
#[1] 1 0
```

Comment: I want the variable value to remain in the dataframe

Comment: @firmo23 I think you need to assign (`<-`) back to the same object.  Updated the post